# Spring WebFlux: Unit testing of Mono

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, project-reactor

I have the following service

```java
@Service
public class TestService {
    @Autowired
    TestService1 testService1;
    
    @Autowired
    TestService2 testService2;
    
    @Autowired
    TestService3 testService3;
    
    @Autowired
    TestService4 testService4;

    public Mono<DataResponse> getData() {
        Mono<String> ts1 = testService1.getMono();
        Mono<String> ts2 = testService2.getMono();
        Mono<String> ts3 = testService3.getMono();
        Mono<String> ts4 = testService4.getMono();
        
        return Mono.zip(ts1, ts2, ts3, ts4)
        .flatmap(resp -> {
             // line XX
             return(Mono.just(new DataResponse(ts1, ts2, ts3, ts4)));
        });
    }
}
```

I'm trying to perform unit testing using Mockito and JUnit.

```java
@SpringBootTest()
public class TestService {
    @InjectMocks
    TestService testService;

    @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
    TestService1 testService1;
    
    @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
    TestService2 testService2;
    
    @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
    TestService3 testService3;
    
    @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
    TestService4 testService4;
    
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public Mono<DataResponse> getData() {
        when(testService1.getMono()).thenReturn(Mono.just(new String()));
        when(testService2.getMono()).thenReturn(Mono.just(new String()));
        when(testService3.getMono()).thenReturn(Mono.just(new String()));
        when(testService4.getMono()).thenReturn(Mono.just(new String()));
                
        Mono<DataResponse> res = testService.getData();
        
        Predicate<DataResponse> p = response -> response != null;
        StepVerifier.create(res.log(), 1).expectNextMatches(p).verifyComplete();
    }
}
```

StepVerifier never executes expectNextMatches if I return Mono.zip(...) from the getData method and never executes code inside flatmap (line XX), the publisher is getting initialized but not able to subscribe to it. But if I return Mono.just() it is working fine.

Following are the logs

```html
12:47:18.576 [main] INFO reactor.Mono.FlatMap.2 - | onSubscribe([Fuseable] MonoFlatMap.FlatMapMain)
12:47:18.587 [main] INFO reactor.Mono.FlatMap.2 - | request(1)
```

What would be the best approach to write unit test cases for this use case with 100% coverage?

Comment: why do you need to `RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS`? I suspect that is the crux of the issue.

Comment: But without `RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS` I am getting null pointer exception in `Mockito.when(...)` as the test services are assigned as null

Comment: wouldn't `RETURNS_MOCKS` work?

Comment: be careful while using the zip operator because an error or empty completion of any source will cause the other source to be cancelled and the resulting Mono to immediately error or complete, respectively. So if you error or complete then flatMap will not be called.

Comment: Removing `RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS` worked. Thank you @SimonBaslé